# Switching off `@grant none` breaks my Greasemonkey script?

Tags: jquery, facebook, greasemonkey, sandbox

I'm running this script on the Facebook homepage. It gets all the conversations in the dock in the bottom and gets their `__FB_TOKEN`s.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name MyScript
// @namespace MyNameSpance
// @include /https?://(www.)?facebook.com(/.*)?/
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js
// @version 0.0.0
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript==
(function () {
  // Don't run on frames or iframes
  if (window.top != window.self) {
    return ;
  }

  window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    var element = $('.fbNubGroup.clearfix.videoCallEnabled');
    console.log('SCRIPT ELEMENT: ', element); // is displayed on the console

    var children = element.children();
    console.log('SCRIPT CHILDREN: ', children); // is displayed on the console

    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      var child = $(children[i]);
      console.log('SCRIPT CHILD: ', child); // is displayed on the console

      /*
      child :
        Object [div.someClasses]
          + 0: div.someClasses
            + __FB_TOKEN: [ 267 ]
      */

      console.log('SCRIPT CHILD[0]: ', child[0]); // is displayed on the console
      console.log('SCRIPT CHILD[0].__FB_TOKEN:', child[0].__FB_TOKEN); // UNDEFINED

      var key = child[0].__FB_TOKEN[0];
      console.log('SCRIPT KEY: ', key); // not displayed
    }
  }, false);
}) ();
```

With `@grant none`, it works as expected and I get:

[image: grant_none]

However, if I change `@grant none` to `@grant GM_xmlhttpRequest`, the script does not work anymore. It gives:

[image: grant GM_xmlhttpRequest]

and throws an exception on the `child[0].__FB_TOKEN` line.

I don't understand why, because the `CHILD[0]` did not change:

[image: child]

Why is changing the `@grant none` breaking the script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you switch from `@grant none` to `@grant GM_xmlhttpRequest`, [Greasemonkey switches the sandbox back on, **as a side-effect**](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1614#issuecomment-8113086).
<sub>(Frankly, all GM developers and scripts should always run with the sandbox on anyway -- with extremely rare exceptions. This avoids "Time bomb" coding problems and head-scratchers like this question.)</sub>

JavaScript objects, arrays, variables, and functions cannot cross the sandbox. But `unsafeWindow` is provided to the Greasemonkey scope as a limited workaround.

Also important for this question:

1. [Greasemonkey (and Firefox) just shut down some of the previously possible solutions using `unsafeWindow`](http://www.greasespot.net/2014/06/greasemonkey-20-release.html).
2. jQuery is a special case and is extra difficult to use to bring non-DOM objects across the sandbox.

## Solution:

1. Since `__FB_TOKEN` is an array, you must use `unsafeWindow` to get it across the sandbox.
2. Trying to use jQuery in this case gives an unacceptably high headache-to-results ratio; so use plain DOM methods.

Putting it all together the script becomes:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _MyScript
// @namespace   MyNameSpace
// @include     /https?://(www.)?facebook.com(/.*)?/
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js
// @version     0.0.0
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==
(function () {
    // Don't run on frames or iframes
    if (window.top != window.self) {
        return;
    }
    window.addEventListener ('load', function () {
        /*--- This unsafeWindow is key. After that, don't use any jQuery
            while trying to get at javascript objects like __FB_TOKEN.
        */
        var element = unsafeWindow.document.querySelector (
            '.fbNubGroup.clearfix.videoCallEnabled'
        );
        /*-- Used console.info to make it easier to spot messages buried
            in all the Facebook console crud.
        */
        console.info ('SCRIPT ELEMENT: ', element);

        var children = element.children;
        console.info ('SCRIPT CHILDREN: ', children);

        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            var child = children[i];
            console.info ('SCRIPT CHILD: ', child);

            /*
            child :
              Object [div.someClasses]
                + 0: div.someClasses
                  + __FB_TOKEN: [ 267 ]
            */
            console.info ('SCRIPT CHILD: ', child);
            console.info ('SCRIPT CHILD.__FB_TOKEN:', child.__FB_TOKEN);

            var key = child.__FB_TOKEN[0];
            console.info ('SCRIPT KEY: ', key);
        }
    }, false);
} ) ();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all these precisions. First, do you know why Chrome isn't impacted by the sandbox? I mean, this is not my real script, but this logic is used inside a bigger script. In Chrome, switching from none to GM_xml... does not change anything, my script is working (I did not test for this one). -- Secondly, I heard of the sandbox but I did not know its consequences, thanks for that! -- Finally, as I quick fix (and because I'm already using jQuery a lot at the moment, I ended up using `element = $(unsafeWindow.document.querySelector('.fbNubGroup.clearfix.videoCallEnabled'));`.

Comment: In Chrome are you using Tampermonkey?  Chrome sandbox is very different from FF sandbox. Chrome+Tampermonkey tries to emulate FF+GM but it's not an exact match and changes depending...  Glad that `$(unsafeWindow...` works for now, but that approach is liable to lead to more headscratchers in the future. ;)

Comment: I'm using Tampermoney, yes. I did notice that it was different from Greasemonkey (for instance, window.load event is not fired at the same time on the facebook homepage. I have to use $(document).ready on Tampermonkey to make the script wait long enough). -- Yes for the $(...) this is just a quick fix. I will remove everything I can about jQuery in a near future! Thanks again for your precisions!!

Comment: You don't need to remove all jQuery.  Just don't use it as part of extracting javascript variables that are defined by the target page.